# Is Microsoft ink and handwriting recognition built into all Windows 7 deployments?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, handwriting

I am trying to add handwriting recognition to my application, I see that with Windows XP the end user needs to have the Tablet PC edition for the recognition to work.

However it is a little ambiguous at to the state of Windows 7 users.

When I consider the deployment of my application, do I need to test for the Tablet PC edition of the operating system or am I just allowed to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be available in most editions of Windows Vista and 7. There is no separate Tablet PC edition any more.

From the [Wikipedia Article on Tablet PCs:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tablet_PC)

> With the succession of Windows Vista, the Tablet PC functionality no longer required a separate edition. Tablet PC support is built into all editions of Windows Vista with the exception of Home Basic and Starter editions. This extends the handwriting recognition, ink collection,[4] and additional input methods to any computer running Vista even if the input device is an external digitizer, a touch screen, or even a regular mouse. Vista also supports Multi-Touch functions and gestures (originally developed for the Microsoft Surface version of Vista) and is now usable by the public with the release of Multi-Touch tablets.
>
> Windows Vista also significantly improved handwriting recognition functionality with the introduction a handwriting recognition personalization tool as well as an automatic handwriting learning tool.